# How do you obtain crestwood?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Im sure I did something wrong....im currently trying to become an assassin .. and I have all the items I need besides the assassin guild leader tokens. But I don't have crestwood on my map yet.. I've talked to everyone I possibly can in skyhold but nothing has happened.. is it possible to miss out on an area?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but try talking to both Josephine and Varric in Skyhold, that should open the War Table mission. It costs 8 power, and unlocks Crestwood instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The option to scout it on the War Table for 8 power opens up after meeting Varric on the battlements.

Answer (score 2):

Its on the Ferelden side of the war map under the title "Find the Warden"